# Range extender for two SSIDs?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-extender

I have a [D-Link DIR-655](http://us.dlink.com/products/connect/wireless-n-gigabit-router/) router that broadcasts two SSIDs, one for the “normal” network and one for the “guest network.” I have dead zones in my house that can’t be addressed by moving the router, so I’d like to use a range extender.

I bought a [D-Link DAP-1320](http://us.dlink.com/products/access-points-range-extenders-and-bridges/wireless-range-extender/), but it will broadcast and connect to only one of my SSIDs. Can anybody advise me how I can extend the range of both SSIDs (i.e., both the “normal” and the ”guest” networks)?